# Determine a user's current local time based on their country ISO code in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a CRON task to run a PHP script that sends emails in the afternoon according to the recipients' local time determined by their country's ISO code.

I don't store dates in UTC, so I can only determine the time zone from the ISO code of my user's country.

My server is configured on the time zone of France (UTC+0200).

How do I select users whose local time is currently afternoon?

```
MySQL users table
    
+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| company    | Country   | Email               | Date                |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ABC        | US        | john.doe@domain.com | 2018-08-19 12:53:58 |
| DEF        | FR        | doe.john@domain.com | 2021-10-04 08:12:27 |
| GHJ        | CN        | john.d@domain.com   | 2022-03-15 17:32:19 |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Countries have more than 1 timezone. Think you'll need to go based off global positioning if you are to take this approach.

Comment: Countries can have more than one timezone, Ex. South Carolina and Washington both are in the US, but the timezone is different.

Comment: You can't, at least not definitively since some countries have multiple time zones. Russian has 8, mainland US 5. Australia 3, Denmark 2. Then you have to account for DST changes which differs worldwide.

Comment: Also the recipient may not be in their default time zone, because they are traveling. It would be easiest to let the user set their preference for when they would like to receive emails.

Comment: Get your users to tell you their preferred timezone, not just their country. Plenty of websites and applications do that, it's not particularly unusual. And for goodness' sake, store your dates in UTC for everyone's sanity, including yours.